# Does Versatile Focus apply to weapon proficiency granted by a class sub Ability?

Tags: starfinder

Mechanic's AI: Exocortex has the Combat Tracking at Level 1. This grant them proficiency in longarms and 3rd Level Weapon Specialization: longarms.

Mechanics are proficient initially with small arms.

If I chose Weapon Focus: small arms at level 1 and Versatile Focus at level 3, do I get the effect of Weapon Focus on longarms  I get form AI: Exocortex Combat Tracking ability?

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, it does

[Versatility Focus](http://www.starjammersrd.com/feats/combat-feats/versatile-focus-combat/) says:

> The benefits of Weapon Focus extend to all weapons with which you are **proficient**.

This means you will gain the benefits of [Weapon Focus](http://www.starjammersrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat/) to all weapons which you are proficient, regardless of the origin of that proficiency. Meaning that you could multiclass into [Soldier](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/soldier/), for instance, to gain several proficiencies and obtain a greater benefit from the feat.